# comparator schematic symbol

Tags: operational-amplifier, schematics, comparator

[image]

This schematic appears in a recent question. The triangle may be an op-amp or a comparator, because they both have the same connections. (Why) isn't there a separate symbol for a comparator? The functions of op-amp and comparator are very different.

Or from the document @boardbite writes about in a comment:

[image]

Comment: An [interesting app note from TI](http://encon.fke.utm.my/nikd/latest/sloa067.pdf) related to the "similarities" and the differences (still no etymology though)

Comment: Frankly, I'm glad there is no separate symbol. There is already too many of them. The app note above shows a very nice comparison - the insides of a op amp and a comparator are very similar.

Comment: @Jonny - If there are too many symbols it's because of duplicates for *identical* parts, like US and IEC resistors, several capacitor, current source and logic symbols, etc. For me an opamp and a comparator are different enough (do you *really* think they're very similar???) that the comparator at least deserves an indication.

Comment: @steven: I think they're simillar enough - and since they haven't changed for so many years, apparently the majority of people involved in the industry would agree, or likely do not care. If there was to be a proposed new symbol, it would be very hard to enforce its use. One organization will pick a new symbol, a different one will use their own, and suddenly we have a whole new set of unnecessary symbols. Just like in the case of voltage/current sources, analog/digital signal buses on block diagrams, etc. In principle, different elements should differ, but there should be only one.

Comment: @Jonny - Similar enough? Well, then replace the opamp in that amplifier by a comparator -- just for laughs. "suddenly we have a whole new set of unnecessary symbols". The idea is of course that everybody listens to *me*! :-)

Comment: @steven: Hey - if you manage to convince the entire industry to agree on a new international standard symbol and endorse it everywhere, manage to get software developers to use it in their schematic, pcb, and simulation software... well I certainly won't be complaining!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've never seen a different symbol for comparators, so I had to make up this one:

[image]

The hysteresis symbol refers to the hysteresis which is often built-in into the IC, or otherwise is almost always needed in the circuit. Does this make sense?

**edit**
Olin objects. He's right: it suggests a built-in hysteresis, rather than a required one. So second attempt:

[image]

Comment: Do real-life comparators include hysteresis? The LM339 apparently does not, the data sheet even shows a circuit that adds hysteresis.

Comment: @Wouter - [Some](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21714G.pdf) do, but I don't use comparators frequently enough to have a good idea how many.

Comment: That datasheet even shows the symbol with hysteresis :)

Comment: @Wouter - Heck, yes, I hadn't noticed that :-), (but only once, in most schematics they use the "opamp" symbol)

Comment: I think this is a reasonable symbol only if the comparator really does have hysteresis built in.  Otherwise it would be misleading.

Comment: I don't think you invented either of these.  The first one is shown in the datasheet and [here](http://www.gedasymbols.org/user/stanislav_brabec/symbols/analog/comparator-1.sym) and [here](http://modernpowerelectronicsanddrivers.blogspot.com/2010/12/single-phase-drives-servo-control-mode.html). The second one is [here, 2006](http://www.engr.uidaho.edu/thompson/courses/ME330/lecture/DigitalInteraction.html#_Ref113067342) and [here, 2009](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/tutorials/MT-083.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

I'm not an expert on using op-amp or comparators but from my understanding, many op-amps can be used as comparators, the main difference is that the op-amp uses feedback to define the amplification value and the comparator doesn't care much about a linear output since usually we only need a high or low value from it but essentially they perform quite similarly.

Comment: I'd rephrase as "many op-amps can be used as comparators"...Some won't work well as comparators becuase they have slow recovery from saturation conditions. Others might even draw damaging currents when their input voltages are allowed to diverge.

Comment: AFAIK the same (ideal) component serves both functions, hence the same symbol is used for both. An (ideal) op-amp does not need to be used with feedback.

Comment: @Wouter - the opamp may be usable, but performs far worse. Some comparators are Damn Fast™, like < 500 ps propagation delay. An opamp has frequency compensation and therefore will be much slower.

Comment: @stevenvh I'm not claiming that using a comparator is the same as using a op-amp. The question was about the schematic symbol, and ideally both work very similarly hence the same symbol. They are used in different situations so they have different requirements.

Comment: @stevenh compare the situation of a hf-transistor versus a 3055-type slow-but-high-current transistor. They have the same symbol, but no one in his right mind would use one when the other was required.