# What type of Op Amp or comparator has a schematic symbol with hysteresis like symbol

Tags: schematics, comparator, symbol

I already know it is not a schmitt trigger, it looks like it is used as an open loop amplifier taking a reference voltage on the (+) and the V0 is fed into a schmitt trigger.

[image]

I have no other data. I wonder if it is "made up" like the symbol in  [comparator schematic symbol](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/39404/comparator-schematic-symbol).

Comment: It is clearly not a schmitt trigger because the schematic uses a different (proper) symbol for it, and a scmitt trigger is esentially a comparator with hysteresis.

Comment: I've seen it used in schematics so the reader can instantly knows the output is either a 1 or a 0. This disagrees with your amplifier conclusion so I guess a circuit would be helpful.

Comment: That is not the symbol for hysteresis, but a symbol for "positive-edge". May indicate that the comparator output is being used as an edge trigger.

Comment: I cannot share the whole schematic (work restrictions), sorry.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/39408/11861

Comment: You don't need to share the whole schematic, just the part that concerns you.

Comment: See http://www.engr.uidaho.edu/thompson/courses/ME330/lecture/DigitalInteraction.html#_Ref113067342 ... It appears to be a symbol for an analog comparator, probably used to differentiate it from an opamp. (link provided by endolith)

Comment: @Tut that is what I though too, but the context was a little weird. The circuit looks like a peak detector circuit without the diode.

Comment: I think the schmitt-trigger connected to the output probably indicates it is being used as a comparator, although they could probably have added hysteresis to the comparator (with a positive feedback resistor, swapping the + and - inputs for the logic inversion) and skipped the schmitt-trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a push-pull open-drain output comparator. It has an internal input hysteresis which eliminates output switching due to internal input noise voltage, reducing current draw. ACD's [digital output comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/126508/what-type-of-op-amp-or-comparator-has-a-schematic-symbol-with-hysteresis-like-sy#comment253467_126515) and supercat's [input exceding rail voltage comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/126508/what-type-of-op-amp-or-comparator-has-a-schematic-symbol-with-hysteresis-like-sy#comment253517_126520) were very informative and correct.

But as far as I can tell, no manufacturer uses this symbol. Even the datasheet for the component in the actual circuit.

It should also be noted the schematic is missing a pull up resistor.

Answer (score 2):

The second block in your schematic is clearly a inverter with Schmitt trigger input.  Since the first block was presumably drawn by the same person, I think they are trying to point out that it does NOT exhibit hysteresis, in contrast to the second block.  That's a guess, but I think makes sense.  Usually one doesn't draw anything special to indicate a block has a normal "linear" response.

Comment: Many comparators have open-collector outputs; this can sometimes lead to confusion as to whether the output should be considered "on" or "off" when the "+" input exceeds the "-" input.  Perhaps the rising-edge symbol indicates that the output voltage should be a logic high when "+" exceeds "-".